# Scale RelativeLayout with ImageView and Caption

Tags: android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and a caption which overlaps the image
This layout is centered in another RelativeLayout.

The ImageView should downscale if necessary but not upscale.
Using ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE seems to do exactly this.

It seems to work, if there's enough space around the image (image 1,FWVGA)
Otherwise the ImageView widens and the TextView with it (image 2,WVGA).

I would have expected, that the ImageView would scale down keeping the image's aspect ratio

[image: FWVGA]

[image: WVGA]

Here's my layout:--

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF333333"
android:padding="5dip">
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ex"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"></ImageView>
    <TextView
            android:background="#AAFFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#FF333333"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Caption"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`, for downscaling that fits the `src` image.